# Excel group items/rows in table

Tags: excel

I have a list like the following:

- Remember to by groceries

  - Bananas
  - Apples
- Align with people

  - Person A
  - Person B
  - Person C

Is there a way that I can put the list into an excel table, that will reflect the indentation, so sub-items will belong to the same group, even if I sorted the list?

If I sorted this list alphabetically I would expect it to look like this instead:

- Align with people

  - Person A
  - Person B
  - Person C
- Remember to by groceries

  - Apples
  - Bananas

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then either edit your original question to improve it, or ask a new one if the original has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

For grouping items in a table, the basic Excel feature "Subtotals" exists, as explained in [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a).

One drawback: you need to have an extra column (like number of entries) for making it work.

Comment: As far as I understand, the subtotal function does not do either of the things I wish.
1) The indentation is not reflected in the table
2) The list cannot be sorted according to the groupings.

The only thing that subtotals does is to add algebraic expression into my list, that I do not need.